# reverse words in a sentence pythonic

Tags: python

I am trying write pythonic code to reverse the words in a sentence

ex:

```
input: "hello there friend"

output: "friend there hello"
```

code:

```
class Solution:
    def swap(self, w):
        return w[::-1]

    def reverseWords(self, s):
        w = self.swap(s).split()
        return ' '.join(for x in w: swap(x))
```

I am having a bit of trouble getting this to work. I need help on the return statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the swap/split in the wrong order. Use this instead:

```
w = self.swap(s.split())
```

Then your return shouldn't need to do any comprehension:

```
return ' '.join(w)
```

Answer (score 2):

While there's not a whole lot wrong with wrapping it in a class, it's not exactly the most pythonic way to do things. Here's a shorter version of what you're trying to do:

```
def reverse(sentence):
    return ' '.join(sentence.split()[::-1])
```

Output:

```
In [29]: reverse("hello there friend")
Out[29]: 'friend there hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one

```
def revereString(orgString):
  result = []
  splittedWords = orgString.split(" ")
  for item in range(len(splittedWords)-1, -1, -1):
    result.append(splittedWords[item])
  return result

print(revereString('Hey ho hay'))
```